# Proving an algorithm correct by induction

Tags: algorithm, correctness, induction, eiffel, proof-of-correctness

I am supposed to prove an algorithm by induction and that it returns 3<sup>n</sup> - 2<sup>n</sup> for all n >= 0. This is the algorithm written in Eiffel.

```
P(n:INTEGER):INTEGER;
  do
    if n <= 1 then
        Result := n
    else
        Result := 5*P(n-1) - 6*P(n-2)
    end
  end
```

My understanding is that you prove it in three steps. Basis step, Inductive Hypothesis, and Proof of completeness. This is what I have currently.

**Basis:**

P(0) returns 0, and 3<sup>0</sup> - 2<sup>0</sup> = 0.

P(1) returns 1, and 3<sup>1</sup> - 2<sup>1</sup> = 1.

**Inductive Hypothesis:**

Assume P(k) returns 3<sup>k</sup> - 2<sup>k</sup> for 0 <= k < n.

**Proof of completeness:**

For n, P(n) returns 5(P(n-1)) - 6(P(n-2))

5(P(n-1)) - 6(P(n-2))

5(3<sup>n-1</sup> - 2<sup>n-1</sup>) - 6(3<sup>n-2</sup> - 2<sup>n-2</sup>) <- Based on inductive hypothesis

This is the part where I get stuck. How the hell am I supposed to reduce this to look like 3<sup>n</sup> - 2<sup>n</sup>?

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but algebra should work.

Comment: Now for the followup question: how do you figure out it's `3^n - 2^n` in the first place?

Comment: @IVlad it was given.

Comment: @Jimenemex: in your program, you wrote `5*g(n-1) - 6*g(n-2)`? What is `g`?

Comment: @geceo indeed. My mistake. should be P(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that 3<sup>n-1</sup> = 3.3<sup>n-2</sup> and 2<sup>n-1</sup> = 2.2<sup>n-2</sup> :

5(3<sup>n-1</sup> - 2<sup>n-1</sup>) - 6(3<sup>n-2</sup> - 2<sup>n-2</sup>)

= 15(3<sup>n-2</sup>) - 10(2<sup>n-2</sup>) - 6(3<sup>n-2</sup>) + 6(2<sup>n-2</sup>)

= 9.3<sup>n-2</sup> - 4.2<sup>n-2</sup>

= 3<sup>n</sup> - 2<sup>n</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
  5(3^(n-1)-2^(n-1))-6(3^(n-2)-2^(n-2)) =
= 5*3^(n-1)-5*2^(n-1)-6*3^(n-2)+6*2^(n-2) =
= 5*3^(n-1)-5*2^(n-1)-2*3^(n-1)+3*2^(n-1) =
  --------- ========= --------- =========
= 3*3^(n-1)-2*2^(n-1) = 
= 3^n - 2^n
```